# Javascript functions not working on github pages (but working locally)

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

I am able to load my javascript functions on the local machine (local host). **But on github pages, it is not working** (but marked as successfully pushed and "deployed".)

I have included the file in **tags.html** as

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        let currentTag = "";
        const queryTag = getQuery().tag;
     
        if (queryTag) {
            currentTag = queryTag;
            filterByTagName(currentTag)
        }
        //binding event
        $(".tag").click((e) => {
            currentTag = e.target.dataset.tag;
            filterByTagName(currentTag);
            updateQueryString(currentTag);
        })
    });
   
    function getQuery() {     
        var params = {};  
    
        window.location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, 
            function(str, key, value) { 
                params[key] = value; 
            }
        );     
        
        return params; 
    }

    function updateQueryString(tagName) {

        const path = `${location.protocol}//${location.host}${location.pathname}?tag=${tagName}`;
        window.history.replaceState({ path }, '', path);
    }

    function filterByTagName(tagName) {
        $('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');

        $('.post-list').each((index, elem) => {
            //elem -> element (ex. div) has data-tag1
            if (!elem.hasAttribute(`data-${tagName}`)) {
            $(elem).addClass('hidden');
            }
        });
        $(`.tag`).removeClass('selected');
        $(`.tag[data-tag=${tagName}]`).addClass('selected');
    }
</script>
```

The page I need to fix is https://popla0428.github.io/tags/

The code is at https://github.com/popla0428/popla0428.github.io
--> **At this tag page, I want to filter the posts by tag icon, and that's why I add the  above.**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `it is not working` - any debugging info to share? error messages? expected results vs actual results, etc. You know, the basic info - looks like you added code that uses jqeery - does jqeery exist on that page?

Comment: @Bravo Thank you for your help (first reply..!). I've just resolved my problem by just... deleting all annotations (//). Still wondering why it did work on local host, but anyway I solved it now.

Comment: some code minifier is probably not handling comments well - though, I see none in your code - oh, wait ... I'm blind